# Can't get ui-views include in templates to include a view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've studied this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names to exhaustion.  I'm trying to get the following working:

```
...
<div ui-view="mdd"></div>
...
```

Which will get filled with a partial (or template or whatever you want to call it) which includes a view:

```
<div class="well" ng-controller="planningCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">
                Add a plan
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <div ui-view="plan"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
Debug<br />
<pre>{{state}}</pre>
<pre>{{stateParams}}</pre>
```

which if rendered statically would be:

```
...
<div ui-view="mdd">
    <div ui-view="plan"></div>
</ui-view>
...
```

And I can't figure out how to get the ui-router to plug a partial in to the plan view when the planning template is loaded.  I get the plan template just fine, but I can't get the initial view into the plan view.

Here's my config for the app:

```
    .config(
        [
            '$stateProvider'
            , '$urlRouterProvider'
            , function(
                $stateProvider
                , $urlRouterProvider)
            {
                /*
                 * Make sure that a default path is defined for when no
                 * state matches.
                 */

                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('welcome') ;

                /*
                 * These are states which will get more complicated when I start
                 * to nest views.
                 */

                $stateProvider
                    .state(
                        'login'
                        , {
                            url: '/login'
                            , views:
                            {
                                'mdd': {
                                    templateUrl: "view/login.html"
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    .state(
                        'planning'
                        , {
                            url: '/planning'
                            , views:
                            {
                                'mdd': {
                                    templateUrl: "view/planning.html"
                                    , controller: 'planningCtrl'    // you have to specify the controller here using ui-router.
                                }
                                , 'plan@planning':
                                {
                                    templateURL: 'view/plan/welcome.html'
                                    , controller: 'planningCtrl'    // you have to specify the controller here using ui-router.
                                }
                            }
                        })
/*                  .state(
                        'planning.welcome'
                        , {
                            views:
                            {
                                'plan@':
                                {
                                    templateURL: 'view/plan/welcome.html'
                                }
                            }
                        })*/
                    .state(
                        'welcome'
                        , {
                            url: '/welcome'
                            , views:
                            {
                                'mdd':
                                {
                                    templateUrl: "view/welcome.html"
                                }
                            }
                        }) ;
            }
        ]) ;
```

and I've tried a number of variations on the views and state names with no joy.  Any pointers would be appreciated.  I'm probably doing something obvious wrong, but if I knew what it was, I wouldn't be asking.

I did some more poking, still puzzled, but maybe this will help somebody figure this out.  Here's the HTML that gets generated including a bit of debugging information from the ui-router about what state it's in.  This is the partial embedded in the mdd view but failing to have another view (a welcome page) embedded in the plan view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ng-scope" ng-app="mdd" lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Divorce Decisions</title>
    <link href="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/mdd.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/sessionSrvc.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/userSrvc.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/mddCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/loginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="My%20Divorce%20Decisions_files/planningCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="ng-scope" ng-controller="mddCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body"><a href="#/welcome" ui-sref="welcome">My Divorce Decisions</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#/welcome" ui-sref="welcome">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="" href="#/planning" ui-sref="planning" ng-show="isLoggedIn()">Begin Planning</a></li>
                <li><a class="ng-hide" href="#/login" ui-sref="login" ng-hide="isLoggedIn()">Sign In</a></li>
                <li><a class="ng-scope" ng-click="logout()" ng-show="isLoggedIn()" ng-controller="loginCtrl">Sign Out</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="ng-binding" ng-show="isLoggedIn()">esplanner</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- uiView: mdd --><div class="ng-scope" ui-view="mdd"><div class="well ng-scope" ng-controller="planningCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">
                Add a plan
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <!-- uiView: plan --><div class="ng-scope" ui-view="plan"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><span class="ng-scope">
Debug</span><br class="ng-scope">
<pre class="ng-binding ng-scope">{"url":"/planning","views":{"mdd":{"templateUrl":"view/planning.html","controller":"planningCtrl"},"plan@planning":{"templateURL":"view/plan/welcome.html"}},"name":"planning"}</pre>
<pre class="ng-binding ng-scope"></pre>
</div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>

</body></html>
```

Looking at this: http://plnkr.co/edit/g9wgfMkD6TE3eqhDpkM1?p=info

the state information says this should be working and it isn't.

Comment: FWIW, the console doesn't show any http requests to get the planning.welcome template loaded.  It shows the planning view being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after another few hours and experimentation, I got this working.  One missing piece in my brain was that the index page of the application is the root for displaying views and isn't in the state table.  This isn't explicitly discussed in the documentation for ui-router but strongly implied by the example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7FD5Wf?p=preview

A second piece is that you really have to specify the controller to be used by each view.  I discovered by accident that putting ng-controller tags in doesn't seem to work.  I don't know if that's a bug or a feature, but it's works this way so I'll continue to do it right or wrong.

The third missing piece was that (for my application and I suspect most) the planning view I use never gets instantiated by itself, so it should have been abstract to get the template displayed and then the child state gets injected into the parent state (as ui-router says it does).  Since I don't need parallel views at the moment, I could get rid of the view names in the divs and my state table turned into:

```
.config(
    [
        '$stateProvider'
        , '$urlRouterProvider'
        , function(
            $stateProvider
            , $urlRouterProvider)
        {
            /*
             * Make sure that a default path is defined for when no
             * state matches.
             */

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('welcome') ;

            $stateProvider
                .state(
                    'login'
                    , {
                        url: '/login'
                        , templateUrl: "view/login.html"
                        , controller: 'loginCtrl'
                    })
                .state(
                    'planning'
                    , {
                        url: '/planning'
                        , abstract: true
                        , templateUrl: "view/planning.html"
                        , controller: 'planningCtrl'
                    })
                .state(
                    'planning.welcomeToPlan'
                    , {
                        url: '/welcome'
                        , templateUrl: 'view/plan/welcome.html'
                        , controller: 'planningCtrl'
                    })
                .state(
                    'welcome'
                    , {
                        url: '/welcome'
                        , templateUrl: "view/welcome.html"
                        , controller: 'mddCtrl'
                    }) ;
        }
    ]) ;
```

and things began to work.

Sorry for the wasted bandwidth and my being thick about this.  ui-router is way cool and makes the design of my app a whole lot more intuitive.